# How MySQL replicate the rows in a table ? and in which order

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication

I have a master server and slave db setup for replication.

I'm trying to pull the rows from a table in a slave db and some rows are being missed. Example scenario given below:

Say Current time 12:00:00

I pull the rows from 11:00:00 to 12:00:00 from the table in slave db based on timestamp based column. (update constraint -modified datetime of the row)

Lets say I got a count of 100 and MAX of modified date as 11:45:00 (replication lag of 15 mins, PS : rows are being inserted every second continuously in master) from the resultset.

Say at 12:45, when there is no replication lag,  if I run the count of rows from 11:00:00 to 11:45:00 I get a count of 150 in the slave db.

Question:
How does MYSQL replicate the rows in a table? IN what order?

Comment: Are you using statement-based or row-based replication?